# iPhone Apps pause update when screen is locked

Tags: ios-appstore

It seems that when updating multiple Apps and locking the screen, updates are not completed until reopening the phone.

Once I used the 'Update All', which started updating, before going to sleep, only to find hours later that most of the Apps are waiting in some 'installing' stage. Once I unlocked the phone, it took 5 minutes for them to finish.
Can't tell if this is intended and what are the reasons.

It use to be that when I used the 'Update All', close the phone (locked screen) and come back 10 minutes later and everything is updated.

Comment: Just confirming this is a real issue, having this as well. So far only working solution is to keep phone unlocked with display turned on until updates finish :/